# openssl problems on understanding bio_push

Tags: openssl

I am currently writing a program in C that should verify a file from a sign file + the public key.

I copied together the following code from the openssl binary code:

```
#include <BeTypes.h>
#include <mtypes.h>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

typedef struct {
    char *signature;
    int len;
} Signature;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024*8

/**
 * @brief reads a public key from PEM File
 *
 * @return EVP_PKEY containing the public key.
 *         Return Value must be released with EVP_PKEY_free();
 */
static EVP_PKEY *getPubKeyFromPEM(const char *filename) {
    EVP_PKEY *pubkey = NULL;
    BIO *bio_publickey = BIO_new_file(filename, "r");
    pubkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio_publickey, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bio_publickey);
    return pubkey;
}

/**
 * @brief Reads Signature File
 * @param filename_signature File path to signature file
 * @param signature_maxlen   Max Len for the Signature Buffer
 * @return Signature containing len and the signature data
 *         Return Value must be released with OPENSSL_free()
 */
static Signature *getSignature(const char *filename_signature, int signature_maxlen) {
    BIO *bio_signature = NULL;
    Signature *ret;

    //allocate return Object:
    ret = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(Signature));
    if(ret == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //init return Object:
    ret->signature = OPENSSL_malloc(signature_maxlen);
    bio_signature = BIO_new_file(filename_signature, "rb");
    ret->len = BIO_read(bio_signature, ret->signature, signature_maxlen);

    //Free Read
    BIO_free(bio_signature);

    return ret;
}

BOOL thrusted_checkFile(const char *filename_pubKey, const char *filename_signature, const char *filename_signedfile) {
    BOOL valid = FALSE;

    EVP_PKEY *pubkey = NULL;

    Signature *signature = NULL;

    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx_md = NULL;
    BIO *biomd;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = NULL;
    BIO *input;
    BIO *in;
    EVP_MD_CTX *tctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char *buf = NULL;
    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx;

    //Load Public key:
    pubkey = getPubKeyFromPEM(filename_pubKey);
    if(pubkey == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    signature = getSignature(filename_signature, EVP_PKEY_size(pubkey));

    //creates the thing whoever this thing is...
    biomd = BIO_new(BIO_f_md());
    if(biomd == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Create HashAlgorythm Context
    if(!BIO_get_md_ctx(biomd, &ctx_md)){
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Init pctx:
    if(!EVP_DigestVerifyInit(ctx_md, &pctx, NULL, NULL, pubkey)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    in = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    if(in == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    input = BIO_push(biomd, in);

    BIO_get_md_ctx(biomd, &tctx);
    md = EVP_MD_CTX_md(tctx);

    if(BIO_read_filename(in, filename_signedfile) <= 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    buf = OPENSSL_malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if(buf == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while(TRUE) {
        int i = BIO_read(input, (char *)buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if(i < 0) {
            return FALSE;
        } else if(i == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    BIO_get_md_ctx(input, &ctx);
    valid = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, signature->signature, signature->len) > 0;
    printf("No Error on check!\n");

    return valid;
}
```

I now try to understand this code and try to simplify it.

1. my understanding of a bio is like a stream which can have some thing like a map function in java, so you give it an input it uses a function which is chosen by the ctx and on the output you have the converted values.
2. what I don't understand is, what the BIO_push does?
   I don't understand the difference when I am using biomd directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually BIO is not like a stream with map function. BIO is a Buffer IO that use as input or output memory for OpenSSL library.

BIO_PUSH append second argument to the first one. That means in your code "BIO in" appends to "BIO biomd".

**You can find more info about it in [BIO_PUSH manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_push):**

> For these examples suppose md1 and md2 are digest BIOs, b64 is a
>   base64 BIO and f is a file BIO .
>
> If the call:
>
> BIO_push(b64, f); is made then the new chain will be b64-chain. After
>   making the calls BIO_push(md2, b64); BIO_push(md1, md2); the new chain
>   is md1-md2-b64-f. Data written to md1 will be digested by md1 and md2,
>   base64 encoded and written to f. It should be noted that reading
>   causes data to pass in the reverse direction, that is data is read
>   from f, base64 decoded and digested by md1 and md2. If the call:
>
> BIO_pop(md2); The call will return b64 and the new chain will be
>   md1-b64-f data can be written to md1 as before.